# Why is a TimerTask not reusable with a new Timer object?

Tags: java, timer

The `Timer` (`java.util.Timer`) doc describes the `cancel` method as one that affects the Timer and it states that the timer cannot be used after cancellation.  So I instantiate a new `Timer`.  Why will it not let me re-use the argument `task0` in this example?  I'm not even invoking `purge` which is described as making tasks GC-eligible.  Until it might be explained to be otherwise, I claim `Timer` class should not affect a `TimerTask` object that is merely an argument to it.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long delay = 3000L;

        Timer timer0 = new Timer();
        Task task0 = new Task();
        timer0.schedule(task0, delay);
        timer0.cancel();

        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(task0, delay); // throws an exception if we use task0

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        timer1.cancel();
    }
}

class Task extends TimerTask {
    Task() {
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("task was invoked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Allowing this would be error prone, since `task0` could still be running when scheduled again by another timer. (Note that `cancel()` does not *terminate* the task.)

Note that if `task0` is managed by a single `Timer`, the same task will never be executed concurrently with itself (regardless if it is executed with fixed-delay or with fixed-rate).

If you *really want* such behavior, the work around would be to let `task0` and a `task1` wrap a common object:

```
class Task extends TimerTask {
    Runnable runnable;
    Task(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

And then execute it like this:

```
// "Wrapped" (and thus shared) by task0 and task1 below.
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("task was invoked");
    }
}



Timer timer0 = new Timer();
Task task0 = new Task(runnable);
timer0.schedule(task0, delay);
timer0.cancel();


Task task1 = new Task(runnable);
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
timer1.schedule(task1, delay); // throws an exception if we use task0

Thread.sleep(5000);
timer1.cancel();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TimerTask.java.html

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Timer.java.html

The TimerTask class is just a thin extension of Runnable which tracks a bit of metadata about scheduling (namely: next execution time).  But, if you schedule it on two timers, there's still only one next execution field, so one timer would overwrite the next execution time of the other, which is almost certainly not what you want, so it tracks that it's been scheduled before, and throws an exception in Timer, instead.

If it allowed this, you'd get rather unexpected behavior.

Comment: That's the most backward reasoning I've ever heard. If the contract of the class would allow it to be scheduled by several timers, it would *obviously* not have had one field for next execution time.

Comment: @aioobe - perhaps, but it's the only actual answer to: "I claim Timer class should not affect a TimerTask object that is merely an argument to it." It probably _shouldn't_, but the implementation of Timer/TimerTask, well, isn't good. 

You shouldn't to know anything about special about TimerTask - as the user, you're not going to use any of that state, it's just for the Timer.  So Timer should be managing it - you should be able to pass a raw runnable and have it keep state.  Like ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, which is in practically every way better (and should be used instead)

Answer (score 1):

This also is a problem if a timer task wants to re-schedule itself in the *same* Timer - maybe with a different delay this time.
This would allow me for example to implement something like an exponential backoff algorithm (retry a task, with exponentially growing delays.

It seems such a timer task with variable delays can be most comfortably implemented by using a ScheduledExecutorService, because this class does not pose such restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a method to return the same task and then schedulde it to the same timer or different timers:

```
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class Tester {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            long delay = 3000L;
            Timer timer0 = new Timer();
            timer0.schedule(createTask(), delay);

            Timer timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.schedule(createTask(), delay); 
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            timer1.cancel();
            
            // purge all canceled tasks from timers
            timer0.purge();
            timer1.purge();
            
        }
    }

    Task createTask() {
        Task task0 = new Task();
        return task0;
    }

    class Task extends TimerTask {
        Task() {
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("task was invoked");
            // here do something
            cancel(); // stop it.
        }
    }
```